# Publishing iOS app not possible

Tags: appcelerator

I'm using Appcelerator Studio on a Mac (build: 4.5.0.201602170821) and it seems that all of a sudden the publishing of iOS apps stopped working. Android publishing is working fine.

First I ran all the possible updates and rebooted, but with no result. I found some similar issues here on Stackoverflow and on the old Appcelerator community but they aren't working for me.

The log shows me this:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-03-03 17:13:08.286
>   !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
>   !STACK 0
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean**
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:62)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)...

Obviously this log is much longer ;)

So I reinstalled Appcelerator Studio and stil get this issue. Does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this has to do with the WWDR renewal: http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/experiencing-ios-certification-issues-check-your-wwdr-intermediate-certificate/

After installing the certificate publishing for iOS is working fine.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. I wonder if you would get the same error if you don't have the WWDR? Could you please check if this is a known issue at [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket so we can fix this for future events. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: I just checked, but without the certification I get: a clear error in the console. So maybe this is only with an expired certification or it is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try publishing your iOS app using "Application Loader"

Steps:

1> Archive the app using Appcelerator studio

2> Export it from Organizer(from xCode)

3> click on Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader

Comment: Archiving was not possible, so I don't understand this answer. I was trying to run Project->Publish->Distribute - Apple iTunes Store. 

The solution is posted below.